# Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - '404 : NotFound ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

When triggering a web activity daily in ADF, I am getting an error
*"Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - '404 : NotFound', message - 'The requested endpoint(url) does not exist on the server. Please verify the request server and retry.'"*

The Web Activity calls a post API. This works most of the time but fails like once in a week.

Comment: Which URL you are using can you provide sample?

Comment: Sample url https://sample/api/Alert/SendEmail

Comment: This error can occur if the URL is incorrect or pipeline which you are trying is not published. Also, once check the URL you are using has not any spelling mistakes.

Comment: The URL is correct, on random days it is not working and other days it works.

Comment: then it might be issue with your URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows that there is a connectivity issue between the ADF and the URL.

If the error occurs only once a week, you need to check the URL directly without the ADF at the same time the ADF fails to be sure there is no reachability issue from the URL itself

Tip: apply an ADF retry [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities?tabs=data-factory#activity-policy).

Also, you can track the error pattern if it happens at the same time. so most probably it is a URL issue due to resource utilization or so

Comment: Yes. Retry options is also what am seeing left to do. But what confuses me is the error "The requested endpoint(url) does not exist on the server". It says endpoint does not exist and not a connection issue. But the endpoint does exist.